# Can I append or create a new query string with one line of regex in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am trying to append a querystring parameter, 
"q=1" to a URL with a specific directory.  some URLs will have querystrings others won't.  the way I currently do it is by writing 2 rules. first processes if there is a query string variable if not then the other processes.    Is there a way I can consolidate the below code on one line?

```
RewriteRule ^/xyz/(.*)?(.*)  /zyz/$1?=$2&q=1 [NC,L]  
RewriteRule ^/zyz/(.*)  /zyz/$1?q=1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: doesn't `$1?=$2&q=1` result in an invalid query string?  Given that `$1` is "a" and `$2` is "b", that would result in "/zyz/a?=b&q=1".  It's missing the key part in the "b" key, value pair.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to capture query string (and you cannot from `RewriteRule`). Just use `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^xyz/?$  /zyz/q=1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

`QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

---

Since this turned out to be IIS not Apache, following rules will work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lq=1
RewriteRule ^/xyz/(.*)\?(.*) /xyz/$1?q=1&$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lq=1
RewriteRule ^/xyz/(.*) /xyz/$1?q=1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: thanks didn't know about the qsa flag.  however you can capture querystring in htaccess ?(.*) does that I did it all the time, not as much now that I know of this flag

Comment: ive voted this answer up since its helpful but it accept answer,  the QSA flag doesn't work if there is not a ? in the original request, which is what Im trying to solved.

Comment: Even if  these is no query string originally then also above answer will work as QSA will just do nothing but adding an empty query string to the new query parameters.

Comment: Also QUERY_STRING is captured from `RewriteCond` not from `RewriteRule`

Comment: really tried hard to get this to work the  way you suggested.  I think one problem is Im use IsapiRewrite3 on IIS and it has a little different implementation of QSA where it only works if there is a QS.  Also strugled with the capture group picking up the original QS.  I finally gave up and got it to work the long way.   Although your suggestions did help with the rewrite condition for QS since I needed to check for q=1 to prevent infinite loop

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lq=1  
RewriteRule ^/xyz/(.*)\?(.*)  /xyz/$1?q=1&$2 [NC]  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lq=1  
RewriteRule ^/xyz/(.*)  /xyz/$1?q=1  [NC

Comment: Ah my answer was with the impression that it is Apache not IIS. There are some notable difference between both rewrite engines. I will update the answer with a note.